# Is it possible using table-hover to include 2 <tr>s in a row per case?

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

Using table-hover in Bootstrap and having a nested table, can I include the nested table in the hovering effect when I hover the row before nested?

I have searched if this has been asked before but no luck so far.
In my case since the second row is related to the nested table, I need the hover effect to be applied simultaneously in both the row and the nested table so the user can understand that they are related.

Below follows the code I am using:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
          <head></head>
          <body>
    
        <div id="div1" class="table-responsive">
          <table id="1" class="table table-hover table-sm align-middle w-auto">
            <thead class="align-middle">
              <tr style="border-style: inherit; border-color: #000000; background-color: #f6f6f6;">
                <th scope="col" style="text-align: center;">Col1</th>
                <th scope="col" style="text-align: center;">Col2</th>
                <th scope="col" style="text-align: center;">Col3</th>
                <th scope="col" style="text-align: center;">Col4</th>
                <th scope="col" style="text-align: center;">Col5</th>
                <th scope="col" style="text-align: center;">Col6</th>
                <th scope="col" style="text-align: center;">Col7</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td style="text-align: center;">1a</td>
                <td style="text-align: center;">1b</td>
                <td style="text-align: center;">1c</td>
                <td style="text-align: center;">1d</td>
                <td style="text-align: center;">1e</td>
                <td style="text-align: center;">1f</td>
                <td style="text-align: center;">1g</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td style="text-align: center;">2a</td>
                <td style="text-align: center;">2b</td>
                <td style="text-align: center;">2c</td>
                <td style="text-align: center;">2d</td>
                <td style="text-align: center;">2e</td>
                <td style="text-align: center;">2f</td>
                <td style="text-align: center;">2g</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td colspan="7">
                  <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-sm align-middle mb-0 w-75" style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
                    <thead class="align-middle">
                      <tr class="bg-info text-white" style="border-style: inherit; border-color: #000000;">
                        <th scope="col" style="text-align: center;">Col1-nested</th>
                        <th scope="col" style="text-align: center;">Col2-nested</th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <td style="text-align: center;">1a-nested</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center;">1b-nested</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td style="text-align: center;">2a-nested</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center;">2b-nested</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                        <td style="text-align: center;">3a-nested</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center;">3b-nested</td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </body>
    
    </html>
```

I have created it in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qkcb0hgx/2/) so it is easier to understand how it looks like.

Comment: Note that you use bootstrap 3.1 but specified `bootstrap-5` in tags

Comment: You are correct, I missed that. I have updated JSFiddle using 5.1.3. Thank you